# Does the Netherlands "orientation visa" remain available to me if I received an MVV but do not travel?

Tags: visa, netherlands

Consider the following situation:

- I am a national of a country that requires a visa to the EU for practically any purpose (i.e, am not visa-exempt)
- I am eligible for the Netherlands [one-year orientation visa permit](https://ind.nl/en/residence-permits/work/residence-permit-for-orientation-year), but live outside the Netherlands.
- I decide to apply for the permit.
- I get the MVV but choose **not** to travel (for instance because I got a job offer elsewhere)

My question is: because the MVV is valid for 90 days, whether I can re-apply for the orientation visa if I choose not to travel the first time (as long as I remain eligible to use the scheme). This does not seem to be described on the internet; only that the orientation visa can be used only once (which I presume applies if I actually go there and actually use the visa, such as getting the residence card). Thanks in advance.